# How to insert a variable in a nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my Python code. I want to replace the value of `id` with the variable `account_id` in the `data` dictionary. The current value of `id` in the code is 12345.

```
import requests

stacks = [{ "Key": "acc_1", "Value": "11111" },{ "Key": "acc_2", "Value": "22222"}]


for stack in stacks:
    account_id = stack['Value']
    account_name = stack['Key']
    data = {"query":"{\n  actor {\n    account(id: 12345 ) {\n      nrql(query: \"SELECT count(*) from Log where logtype = \u0027alb\u0027 AND elb_status_code = \u0027502\u0027 OR elb_status_code = \u0027504\u0027 AND target_processing_time = -1 AND response_processing_time = -1 FACET  elb_status_code, request since 12 hours ago\", timeout: 500) {\n        results\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n", "variables":""}
```

I tried to use `.format`, but it didn't work.  Note:- I am not a python developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
splitted1 = data["query"].split("account(id:")
splitted2 = splitted1[1].split(")",1)
data["query"] = splitted1[0]+"account(id:"+str(account_id)+")"+splitted2[1]
```

It would be better with regex, but I think, this should work.

Comment: But is it really nescassary to replace the value in the string? Why don't you declare your string like this instead of replacing afterwards?

data = {"query":"{\n  actor {\n    account(id: "+str(account_id)+" ) {\n      nrql(query: \"SELECT count(*) from Log where logtype = \u0027alb\u0027 AND elb_status_code = \u0027502\u0027 OR elb_status_code = \u0027504\u0027 AND target_processing_time = -1 AND response_processing_time = -1 FACET  elb_status_code, request since 12 hours ago\", timeout: 500) {\n        results\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n", "variables":""}

Comment: Using format won't function because you have { and } in your string. You would have to escape them. I think it's easier to concatenate the strings.